# Execution of Windows batch file using Java ProcessBuilder always returns exit code 0

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute a batch file and get the error code from it in Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit.

My batch file is c:\test.cmd and contains a single line:-

```
exit 1
```

My code for executing the batch file is:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Process process = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\test.cmd").start();
       System.out.println(process.waitFor());
}
```

The output is zero. If I try with:-

```
new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "c:\\test.cmd"}
```

the result is again zero.

There doesn't seem to be much magic to the ProcessBuilder API that I'm missing. Can anyone see where my code is going wrong?

Shouldn't I be able to capture the exit code of the batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong (or different) with my PC.  The Apache Commons Exec project source code I downloaded failed unit tests when capturing return codes. Looks to be unsolvable on my PC and haven't found a workaround.

Comment: Worth mentioning the exact same code give me a result of one on a Windows server so looks to be specific to my version of Windows 7.